# NodeJS Express: Repopulate form after error found

Tags: node.js, forms, validation, express

I think I am really close to figuring this out. I'm just trying to repopulate my form data after an error is found. In my example below, age and platelet_count should both repopulate but they don't.

Model name: Store.js

```
storeController.js

exports.store_create_post = [

    body('age', 'Please enter age').isLength({ min:1 }),
    body('platelet_count', 'Please enter platelet count').isLength({ min: 1 }),


    // sanitizeBody('age').escape(),

    (req, res, next) => {
        //Extract the validation errors from a request.
        const errors = validationResult(req);

        //Store form values for post data when error caught
        var predModel = new Store(
                { 
                    age: req.body.age, 
                    platelet_count: req.body.platelet_count
                }
        );

        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            //Validation or Sanitation checks did not pass
            res.render('predictionModel', {title: 'Risk Calculator', Store: predModel, errors: errors.array()});
            return;

        }
```

I think that my problem is that I cant figure out what the argument in res.render (Store: predModel) is doing. I can switch the argument backwards (predModel: Store) and it still works the same.

Here are my routes:

```
index.js

//Get request for PredctionModel Form
router.get('/predictionModel', storeController.store_create_get);

//Post request for PredictionModel
router.post('/predictionModel', storeController.store_create_post);
```

Any advice is appreciated.

Update. Here is my form page with most of the content removed for easy viewing:

```
_modelForm.pug

mixin predictionModelForm(store = {})


    form(action="/predictionModel" method="POST" class="card")

        label(for="age") How old is the patient (years)?    
            input(type='number', name='age', style='width: 100px;', placeholder="40-89")

        input(type="submit" value="Predicted Risks" class="button" style='width: 50%;')
```

Comment: can you attach the file which contain the form?

Comment: I updated my post to include the form content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use your constructor an your rendered object. Define a simple object

```
var predModel = { 
    age: req.body.age, 
    platelet_count: req.body.platelet_count 
}
```

and Render it like this

```
res.render('predictionModel', {title: 'Risk Calculator', predModel: predModel, errors: errors.array()});
```

and inside your input you can add value this way.

```
input(type='number', name='age', style='width: 100px;', value=predModel.age, placeholder="40-89")
```

Also, since you render the same pug file, you should check if the properties you render (for example `predModel`) are undefined.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this out. So far I have: value=(undefined===predModel ? '' : predModel.age), based on something I found. Doesnt work yet though.

Comment: try this `value=(predModel ? predModel.age : ' ')`

Comment: That doesn't work either but feels cleaner at least.

Comment: No, but I have found that if I do this: value=(predModel ? predModel.age : '3'), the value 3 will show up if I open the page fresh. But if I submit the form and hit an error, the placeholder text will take its spot instead of the 3. So it seems after I hit submit, it's not reading for a value

Comment: I think it is reading age as a string, because strings dont appear to work either.

Comment: You are right. Try `type='text'` to check if it works

Comment: It's still the same problem as above, but now it works with text. So maybe my form submit is somehow flawed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190659/discussion-between-dimitris-tseggenes-and-ian-ellis).